# JQuery, load elements after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do something like this:

```
<img src="" class="after-all" data="/assets/huge-bg.png" />
<div class="after-all" data="/actions/div-content.html"></div>
```

And in JS

```
$("after-all").loadMissing();
```

I think the best way is build a plugin with recognize method:

```
if (img) $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data'));
if (div) $(this).load($(this).attr('data'));
```

Is this possible ? What is the best way to do this ? How to do this ?

Comment: Images are loaded asynchronously anyway.

Comment: You may be interested in the [preloadjs](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS/demos/mediaGrid) library of createjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$.fn.loadMissing = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is("img")) {
            $this.attr("src", $this.attr("data"));
        } else if ($this.is("div")) {
            $this.load($this.attr("data"));
        }
    });
};
```

Note that you should use another attribute than `data` to store this information. An HTML5 data attribute like `data-content` might be a better solution.